# Android display facebook wall in webview?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

In my application i have a webview which load the facebook page with this url:

```
http://touch.facebook.com/#/profile.php?id=
```

later on i get the user id with the facebook object and concatenate the id with the url so i could load the user's wall in my webview, this used to work fine a few days ago, but for some reason is not working anymore, the id is concatenated to the url, but the webview just loads a facebook login form. I checked the url being loaded and is this:

```
https://touch.facebook.com/?_rdr
```

so, i would like to know what is really happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate your user ID in this link and try again.

rdr#!/profile.php?_user=">http://m.facebook.com/?*rdr#!/profile.php?*_user=

Comment: Ok, I'll try it when i get home.

Comment: what do you mean by concatenate your user id in this link? if my userid is 12345789 where would it appear?